# Transcrypt without java?

Tags: python, transcrypt

I try out the "hello" example in the Transcrypt tutorial but get the following error message:

```
      bash-4.3$ transcrypt hello
      
      Transcrypt (TM) Python to JavaScript Small Sane Subset Transpiler Version 3.9.0
      Copyright (C) Geatec Engineering. License: Apache 2.0
      
      Saving target code in:
      /home/User/hello/__target__/org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js
      Saving minified target code in:
      /home/User/hello/__target__/org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js
      
      Error while compiling (offending file last):
File 'org.transcrypt.__runtime__', line 0, namely:
      
      [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java': 'java'
      
      Aborted
```

Is the error caused by the Google compilier minifier that needs java? Is there any way to run Transcrypt without java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I googled that error and found [this promising GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/issues/5#issuecomment-183699892) which says

> You can now compile without minification, so without Java by using the `-n` switch.

So, try

```
transcrypt -n hello
```